# How to calculate Sundaeswap TVL using DB-sync?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I'm trying to do an exercise where I see if I can calculate Sundaeswap TVL using DB-Sync.
Below is what I have managed to pull out from the database so far regarding Sundaeswap.
However for the UTXOs in the tx_out table I would have expected the payment_cred (which is described in the docs as " For a script-locked address, this is the script hash." to match the script hash. However it doesn't so I'm not sure how to determine the total number of UTXOs locked by Sundaeswap.

[Link](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/d74798c4a1e453fbc6ba4fbb1d785e0534fb8531fd1bc054ceff5b086240d3b5) to the transaction below in case you need it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I wasn't able to reconcile the above but I did find that DeFiLlama post the code they use to calculate TVL (see the Check the code button here: https://defillama.com/protocol/sundaeswap)

So using this I was able to discern the addresses different DApps use and so tracking those intead.